# How to detect if iPhone is in silent mode in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, mute

I have found the answer for objective-c, but couldn't figure out how to translate it to c# for monotouch.

Also, I couldn't find anything in the Xamarian tutorial or reference.

Could someone please give an example of how to do it?

Comment: Can you post a link to the Objective-C?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833304/how-to-detect-iphone-is-on-silent-mode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798891/detect-silent-mode-in-ios5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880560/how-to-find-out-if-the-iphone-is-on-silent-mode

Comment: The summary of those answers is "there were some hacks in old versions of iOS, but they don't work anymore, and were never intended to work in the first place". So why do you try to port broken code to monotouch? Looks like you should find some working objective-c code first.

Comment: my app is based on the sound. so i have to detect if the mute button is on so i could throw some message to the user.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible (since iOS 5), see here:

[Detecting the iPhone's Ring / Silent / Mute switch using AVAudioPlayer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki)

In general, Apple doesn't allow access to things like this.